# How does Aragorn defeat the Wraiths on Weathertop so easily?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, nazgul

I'm showing my ignorance here, but in the Fellowship of the Rings movie Aragorn seemed to drive away the Ring Wraiths away from Weathertop relatively easily. Were the Nine weaker at that point in the story? Were they so focused on Frodo that he took them totally by surprise?

Comment: In the movie version, if I'm recalling correctly, there were only five wraiths involved in that incident ... but I'm not good with LOTR names for places, so perhaps I'm thinking of a different scene or wrong all together. Doesn't Arwen say something to Aragorn like, "There are five wraiths behind you; where the other four are, I do not know."?

Comment: @aSlytherin I'm pretty sure the books had only 5 there too.

Comment: @Kevin - Well, I'm glad I was thinking of the correct scene. So I'm now wondering how a question about Aragorn defeating five wraiths is a duplicate of a question asking how powerful the *nine* wraiths really were. Is the number incidental?

Comment: Aragorn does mention (at least in the books, the movies have massive problems) that they are lucky there are just 5 of the Nine at Weathertop. Aragorn does not drive them away, they leave of their own accord after Frodo is stabbed by a Morgul blade, believing they only have now to wait for the inevitable result of Frodo becoming a wraith himself.

Comment: @aSlytherin "The Nine" is a collective name for the Nazgûl rather than a simple number, and the other question also covers the Weathertop issue, even if there was only five of them there.

Comment: @Eureka -- I didn't know that about "The Nine", but it makes sense because I believe in the movie Saruman tells Gandalf, "The Nine have left Minas Morgul." Or something to that effect. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: I don't see why this is a duplicate. Though related, 90% of what is written in the linked question and answers does not apply to Aragon's encounter.